# Flutter build called multiple times from FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-state

I'm developing an app with an infinite scroll. My scroll is returned inside futurebuilder.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
  future: VideoService.getFeed(page: page),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasData) {
      /*print(snapshot.data);
      print(page.toString());*/

     _tabController = TabController(
          length: (snapshot.data.length + items.length), vsync: this);
      _tabController.addListener(_tabControllerListener);

      items.addAll(snapshot.data);
      items.removeWhere((element) => (element == null));

      return getBody();
    }

    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);}
```

I use tabcontroller to decide when to call my API:

```
_tabControllerListener() {
if ((_tabController.length - 1) == _tabController.index) {
  /*_tabController.index = _tabController.index;*/

  
  setState(() {
   // _tabController = _tabController;
    page = page + 1;
    _tabController = _tabController;
    //items = items;

  });
} }
```

However the build function is called multiple times. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a side effect when building the UI, and that is not desired. The build method should always return a widget and it shouldn't matter how many times is called.
To avoid the future getting called, you need to save it in your state and "trigger" it inside the initState.

```dart
late Future<Feed> getFeedFuture;

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getFeedFuture = VideoService.getFeed(page: 0);

  ...
}

_tabControllerListener() {
  setState(() {
    page = page + 1;
    getFeedFuture = VideoService.getFeed(page: page);
  });
}

...

FutureBuilder(
  future: getFeedFuture,
  ...
```